# java maven eclipse tomcat failed to start NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I'm struggling with eclipse+tomcat configuration. I deployed my app on the cloud but I'd liek to do some changes offline (it's faster) and then deploy something working. I have web project set up using maven. I have 2 dependencies(not mentioning essential javax): `org.json` and `joda-time`. The problem is I can not figure out how to download those dependencies. Every time I want to run the project tomcat fails to start with a long stack trace, but I know that the problem is that line: `Caused by: Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/json/JsonObject`. That means, dependencies jars aren't there(int `WEB-INF/lib` I think). I've tried ppm on project->maven->update project, ppm on server->clean, ppm on server->publish. Also I checked project->properties->Deployment Asembly and Maven Dependencies are there... I've searched a lot thourgh the web and I'm running out of ideas. Thanks for any help, cheers!

UPDATE
pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>openshifttest</groupId>
    <artifactId>openshifttest</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>openshifttest</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
     <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when invoking mvn. -->
     <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app will need. -->
     <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'deployments' folder. -->
     <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
     <id>openshift</id>
     <build>
        <finalName>openshifttest</finalName>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                      <warName>ROOT</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Please post your pom.xml to go to next level.

Comment: In Deployment Descriptor, what is your `Maven Dependencies` to `Deploy Path` mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that tomcat may not be providing Java EE API, please try changing

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

to

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

(remove provided scope).